# Similar function like Listagg in Redshift

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Can someone please suggest me how can I combine multiple rows into one column based on one particular user id in Redshift. I have used Listagg function but Listagg breaks when I combine million rows with size limit error in Redshift.

[image: This is the original table]

I want something like this:
[image: This is what I want but without using Listagg]

I have been using the below query but Listagg breaks when it exceeds the limits

```
SELECT  id,
        LISTAGG(dest_id, '->')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY arriving_time) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS ROUTES,
        CASE
           WHEN arriving_time IS NOT NULL
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
        END AS arrived,
        CASE
           WHEN departing_time IS NOT NULL 
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
        END AS departed,
        row_number()
           OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY departing_time)
           AS RNK
```

Can someone suggest me a better way to achieve this please.

Comment: afaik there's no way around the limit but what is the longest route in chars that you're supposed to get?

Comment: What is the error message? What is the max size one can get in Dest_ID column?

Comment: error: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit
code: 8001
context: LISTAGG limit: 65535
query: 2967853
location: 1.cpp:1001
process: query0_428 [pid=5673]

Comment: This is the error which I am getting. Is there any other way to achieve the results.

Comment: The error states that you are getting a route with almost 3 milion characters in a row. Are you sure this is what you want? Because it feels like you are trying to do something very weird. Please describe what you are trying to accomplish, and not by this particular query, but in general.